# Check for a random element in an array and return it if true

Tags: arrays, json, batch-processing, jq, conditional-operator

I've got several arrays of varying length that may contain an element which begins with `foo` (the name length varying as well), if this element exists I want to return it, e.g. `foo-f-o-o`.

I know how to check for its existence, I successfully tested in

```
{
    "arr": [
        "foo-f-o-o", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quux", "corge", "grault"
    ]
}
```

with the command `type file.json | jq ".arr|contains([\"foo\"])"` and I correctly received `true`.

However, I'm looking for these steps:

1. Detect if an element `foo*` exists
2. If *yes*, return that element's name, in the given case: `foo-f-o-o`
3. If *not*, return `false`

The element `foo.*` could be at any position of the array, that means something like `jq -r ".arr|.[0]"` is not an option here.

Is there a way to apply a regex like `/^foo.*/` in jq for the matching value?

Comment: for your consideration, here's an _alternative_ (i.e. non-jq) solution for the JSON manipulation in your query, based on a unix _walk-path_ utility `jtc`: `<arr.json jtc -w'[arr]:<>i:<$0:false>f>^foo.*<R' -T'{{$0}}'`. If you're interested I can elaborate on the tool usage in a separate answer (PS. I'm a developer of the tool).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex for this particular case, use `startswith`:

```
first(.arr[] | select(startswith("foo"))) // false
```

If you need all matching elements:

```
(.arr[] | select(startswith("foo"))) // false
```

Comment: dabbl0r - If you wanted to specify a regex, you could use test/1, e.g. `test("^foo")`